# pgr_dijkstra is considering one-way streets as bidirectional

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, routing, osm2pgrouting

I imported data from a map extracted from OpenStreetMap. With osm2pgrouting I imported it into PostgreSQL, to be worked with pgRouting and PostGIS. Command used:

```
osm2pgrouting -f DIRECTORY/map.osm -d DATABASE -p 5432 -U postgres -W PASSWD-c mapconfig.xml --addnodes --attributes -- clean
```

He created the following table structure:

[image]

I am using the `pgr_dijkstra` function to calculate a minimum cost route between two locations:

```
SELECT * FROM pgr_dijkstra('
SELECT gid as id, source, target, ST_Length(the_geom::GEOGRAPHY) AS cost, 
ST_LENGTH(the_geom::GEOGRAPHY) AS reverse_cost
FROM ways',
24212, 5521, directed := true
) as di
  JOIN ways
ON di.edge = ways.gid
order by seq;
```

It is working perfectly when I use `directed: = false`. But when I put `directed: = true` pgRouting is returning the same result. This is wrong because even with `directed: = true` he is considering my unidirectional streets as bidirectional. The image below represents some return lines from my query:

[image]

`oneway = YES` and `one_way = 1` is a one-way street that the function should not be returning. `oneway = UNKNOWN` and `one_way = 0` is my two-way street. The image below shows this one-way street that is being considered as a route path, which is wrong, is in the opposite direction of traffic. In the drawing it can be a bit confusing, but the street "Florestano de Macedo" is unidirectional, as shown by the return in the database. The figure is a bit confused because it is a street that passes next to a highway, and on the other side of the highway there is another street. But this problem occurs for any route with `directed: = true`.

[image]

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to prepare/change my data in any way for these cases? Is my query wrong? PgRouting workshops only say to use directed as true or false, they do not mention data preparation for this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are passing in the metric length `ST_Length(geom::GEOGRAPHY)` of each edge `E` as **both `cost` & `reverse_cost`** - rendering it **equal to to the undirected** counterpart.

*pgRouting* realizes ordered graph restrictions via the `[reverse_]cost` parameters; generally speaking, while an **undirected** graph considers only **a single** `cost` per edge `E`, a **directed** graph treats each individual edge `E` as a **pair of directed edges** (`E'[E_from, E_to]` & `E''[E_to, E_from]`), **each having it's own cost** (`cost` -> `E'` & `reverse_cost` -> `E''`).

---

To implement `one_way` restrictions, set the equivalent *cost* parameter to `-1` (-> *excluded from graph*); it is common (but not guaranteed) in OSM data to model `one_way` roads as **restricted in `[E_to, E_from]` direction**, so you'd need to set the `reverse_cost` accordingly:

```
SELECT *
FROM   pgr_dijkstra('
         SELECT gid AS id,
                source,
                target,
                ST_Length(the_geom::GEOGRAPHY) AS cost, 
                CASE
                  WHEN one_way::BOOL THEN -1
                  ELSE ST_Length(the_geom::GEOGRAPHY)
                END AS reverse_cost
         FROM   ways',
         24212,
         5521,
         directed := TRUE
       ) AS di
JOIN   ways
  ON   di.edge = ways.gid
ORDER BY
       seq
;
```

Comment: Hello @geozelot , you helped me a lot with this, thank you very much for the explanation and example. I just didn't quite understand that part: "one_way :: BOOL". It's a typecast, correct? Boolean is only 1 or 0, but in my tests I noticed that the values of one_way as 1, 2 and 3 he is considering and putting the reverse_cost as -1. Is it okay to change reserve_cost to -1 in these cases too, I just didn't understand why I thought the boolean would be just 1 or 0. In this case of ":: BOOL" everything that is different from zero does it consider TRUE?

Comment: Just one more question, if my database is correct, I can also use "oneway = '' YES '' THEN -1", instead of "WHEN one_way :: BOOL THEN -1", right? I found in my database about 1,500 lines where "one_way" is equal to 2 and "oneway" is equal to NO, and about 25 lines where "one_way" is equal to 3 and "oneway" is equal to REVERSIBLE. Analyzing these streets, they are really bidirectional. Thank you very much.

Comment: @EduardoOliveira yes, it is a `CAST`, the `BOOL` type can be cast from 1 or 0. I simply assumed that would be the reason for having the second `one_way` column, but if there are other numbers then you can use the `CASE oneway = 'YES'` you described just as well. Note, though, that the numbers in `one_way` may actually give you hints about the direction of the one way in relation to the topology (i.e. restricted in `from->to` or `to->from` direction), or if it allows certain vehicles (e.g. one way for cars, but bikes are allowed two ways) - check the docs here.